# Mockito doAnswer when is being called for methods other than those in the when

Tags: java, exception, mockito, reset

In one of our test suites we're mocking a method on a spy.

```
@SpyBean(name="myFutureList")
@Autowired
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> myFutureList;

....

doAnswer(invocation -> {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = invocation.getArgument(0);
    future.get();
    invocation.callRealMethod();
    return true;
}).when(myFutureList).add(any());

....

clearInvocations(myFutureList);
```

This *mostly* works but when there's a delay in the test suite exceptions are thrown. Looking into the issue these exceptions seem to occur when `myFutureList.isEmpty()` or `myFutureList.stream()` is invoking the mocked method. i.e. In which case

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = invocation.getArgument(0);
```

blows up with a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

But this method should only be called when `.when(myFutureList).add(any());` is invoked.

Why would this occur?

Comment: Are there any concurrent calls to the spy? My guess would be that the spy blocks on an `add` and blows up on any other call.

Comment: Concurrency is in play. In the debugger I see the `invocation` object is for the "no argument" methods listed above. It'd seem unusual for a blocked call to cause other methods on the spy to run the mocked function.

Comment: Does the error persist when you whiteout the blocking call `future.get()` (ignoring all the new problems that causes)? That is the call that stalls the thread the mock operates on.

Comment: The same issues persist if I comment out `future.get()`

Comment: Hmm, there's little further information to go on here. As you say, it only happens sporadically and I see no other weird things in your snippet (other than maybe annotating myFutureList with both @Autowired _and_ @SpyBean). Since it is the invocation's capture of the argument which is missing, maybe set a break point at the constructor of `InterceptedInvocation` and trace from there.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a full day to debug this problem. But the root cause is a threading bug in Mockito. I raised an issue describing the problem against their repo at

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2289

In short

```
public StubbedInvocationMatcher addAnswer(Answer answer, boolean isConsecutive, Strictness stubbingStrictness) {
    Invocation invocation = this.invocationForStubbing.getInvocation(); <--- Here
    ThreadSafeMockingProgress.mockingProgress().stubbingCompleted();
    if (answer instanceof ValidableAnswer) {
        ((ValidableAnswer)answer).validateFor(invocation);
    }

    synchronized(this.stubbed) {
        if (isConsecutive) {
            ((StubbedInvocationMatcher)this.stubbed.getFirst()).addAnswer(answer);
        } else {
            Strictness effectiveStrictness = stubbingStrictness != null ? stubbingStrictness : this.mockStrictness;
            <-- Here -->
            this.stubbed.addFirst(new StubbedInvocationMatcher(answer, this.invocationForStubbing, effectiveStrictness)); 
        }

        return (StubbedInvocationMatcher)this.stubbed.getFirst();
    }
}
```

Here the local variable `invocation` was against `localConsumerTaskList.add(null)` while the class variable `this.invocationForStubbing` was against `localConsumerTaskList.isEmpty()`. That caused the stubbed method to be registered against `isEmpty()` invocations. This occurs when a thread updates the class variable before the `synchronized` code runs.